# How to determine if two algebra automorphisms of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are similar?

Tags: algebras, clifford-algebras, classical-groups

Given two algebra automorphisms $\phi, \psi: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ of the real algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, we say they are similar if there exists an algebra automorphism $\alpha: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi = \alpha^{-1}\psi\alpha$, or equivalently, $\alpha \phi = \psi \alpha$.

We say that a map $\xi: A \to A$ is an anti-automorphism of an algebra $A$ if it's a linear automorphism of $A$ and for any two elements $a,b \in A$, $\xi(ab) = \xi(b)\xi(a)$.

I'm interested in whether or not there is a general approach to determining if two algebra automorphisms or anti-automorphisms are similar.

Specifically, I'm trying to make my way through Ian R. Porteous's 'Clifford Algebras and the Classical Groups' and problem 2.4 from chapter 2 asks the following:

Prove that:

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & -c \\ -b & d \end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} d & b \\ c & a \end{pmatrix}$

are similar anti-automorphisms of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: As the question essentially asks for a classification of matrices up to conjugation, there is a general method called "canonical forms". For example, two matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ is similar iff they have the same Jordan normal form, and two matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ is similar iff they have the same rational normal form. I guess a classification up to anti-automorphisms is an easy twist of this method.

Comment: The transpose sends the  group of automorphisms to the set of anti-automorphisms. Are there any automorphisms not of the form $A \mapsto  B A B^{-1}$ for some $B \in GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ ? (in your examples $B$ is $ \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$ and $ \pmatrix{1 &  0\\ 0 & -1}$)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

@cjackal I'm not sure I understand. If I were to use canonical forms to show similarity between algebra automorphisms, then would I not need to represent the automorphism by a matrix? I suppose this is possible, if I view $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$, but otherwise I simply have two automorphisms described by their actions on an arbitrary element of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the response. Is the idea that the two matrices you've listed define the automorphisms corresponding to the anti-automorphisms I've listed above by conjugation?

Comment: I think I understand. If every automorphism of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is given by the above formula, then we can represent automorphisms by the elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ that they conjugate by, and this simply reduces to a question about similarity of matrices, which is addressed by @cjackal in terms of canonical forms.

Thanks everyone.